# RDLC Report change font color if value is greater than zero

Tags: c#, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am trying this in the formula options of RDLC report:

### IIf(fields!paid_amt.Value >1,"Black","Red")

But it is not working. Any idea that what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Code seems to okay. You can also try this.

```
=IIF(Fields!paid_amt.Value <> 0 , "Black", "Red")
```